# Formal words for "beside" and "in the best way"

Tags: phrase-request

To translate a text, I wrote:

> Today, the success of products and organizations largely depends on knowledge and innovation. The most successful organizations are those that use these assets **beside** the social capital **in the best way.**

I am not satisfied with "in the best way" and "beside", though don't know much other way to mention them.

I request for more alternative and formal ways to say "use something ... beside something else..." and "to use something in best way"...

By *beside* here I means something like "in conjunction with"..

I am thinking of

> The most successful organizations are those that use these assets alongside social capital in an efficient way.

Comment: I'm not happy with **use** as well. Do we "use innovation"?  And "social capital" -- what is that?  *Make best use of* is the phrase you're searching for, though again, I don't think it works very well with innovation. Innovation is not a resource on the shelf. It is not at hand, to be used. You might as well say "genius".  Those companies that use genius will have success.  It is down in Room 204, waiting to be used.

Comment: @TRomano Thank you, you are right. However, it was a text one colleague requested me to translate. There are some problems in the original Persian text itself. Then I left them almost intact.

Comment: Often an idea is better expressed as a verb. Companies that make best use of the latest knowledge and *innovate* ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest **together with** or **along with**

I would pull **the best** forward, you can then omit **way**

> that make the best use of these assets together with social capital

or use **optimal**

> that make optimal use of these assets together with social capital

while you could use **optimally** at the end of the sentence it feels rather clumsy.